# jQuery - replace contact form with 'thanks message'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a contact form which performs a PHP action. The contact form is connected with validation engine in jQuery. If messege is sent correctly I simply include PHP file with thanks message -  `require_once('success.php');`. After sending message I would like to replace contact form with thanks message without reloading the whole page. Please give me some advices how to do it.
Here is my html:

```
<div id="contactForm">
<form id="expertForm" class="formular" method="post" action="send.php">
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            <input name="email"
                   id="email"
                   class="required email"
                   type="text"
                   size="40"/>
        </label>

        <p>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" rows="5" cols="50" class="required"></textarea>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="submit"
           type="image"
           src="../images/btn-send.png"/>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#expertForm").validate();
</script>
```

In `send.php` I have:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    require_once('success.php');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see an almost **working** demo here http://jsfiddle.net/v7MJA/1/

```
$(function(){
    $("#expertForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!$(this).validate().form()) return false;
        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr('action'),
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'post',
            success:function(msg){
                $("#expertForm").replaceWith(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. Replacement is performed correctly. But there appeared an issue with validation. Although not every input of form is filled, and validation plugin calls errors (they appear on page for about 0.5 sec), the action is executed and email is being sent. I am using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ for validation.

Comment: I have edited the code for you, you can also check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v7MJA/ . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'd better give us some code so that we could help.

Here is the theorical way: use the `success` event of the jquery `ajax`[<sup>**[ref]**</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $("#myformdiv").html("Thanks!");
  }
});
```

assuming that your HTML markup is something like:

```
<div id="myformdiv">
   <form> 
     <!-- form code here -->
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the load function to load a separate page if that's what you need. Replace `html("Thanks!");` with `load("success.php");` and it will load `success.php` as a stand alone page and insert it into that element.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use the [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method to replace the matched elements with the specified content:

```
$("#yourForm").replaceWith("<p>Thanks!</p>");
```

I'm assuming that you're doing something asynchronously to send the form data to the server, so you can just run the above code in the callback:

```
$.post("yourScript.php", function() {
    $("#yourForm").replaceWith("<p>Thanks!</p>");
});
```